# PHP/jQuery Contact Form Not Sending

Tags: php, jquery

I have a contact form which is validated using jQuery.

The issues with the jQuery were solved in another question.

However, I can not get the form to work even when i take out the validation and have it as a standalone PHP file with just the HTML form and the PHP to send it.

There is no error. The page just goes to a blank page after pressing submit and not to the message in the code.

Here is the code - I have a feeling it is something very simple!:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
}
else {
?>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="**REMOVED**/style.css">


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


function isInt(n) {
return typeof n === 'number' && n % 1 == 0;
}

// Form validation
$(".darkBtn").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var email_check = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i;
var email = $("form.form_contact .email").val();

var zipCheck = /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}/i;
var zip = $("form.form_contact .zipcode").val();

var phoneCheck = /^\d+$/;
var phone = jQuery("#contact_form .phone").val();
console.log(phone);

var error = "";

if(!email_check.test(email))
{
error = "Please give a valid email address."

}

if(!zipCheck.test(zip))
{
error = "Please give a valid postcode.";
}

if(!phoneCheck.test(phone) || phone.length != 11)
{
error = "Please give a valid phone number.";
}


// No error ? -> Submit
if(error == "")
{
$(".form_error").hide();
$("form#contact_form").submit();
} else {
$(".form_error").empty().text(error);
$(".form_error").show();
}
});
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu_contact">
<h3>Contact Us</h3>
<hr />
<form method="POST" class="form_contact" id="contact_form">
<label>Title:</label>
<select class="input" name="title">
<option value="no">Please select</option>
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
<option value="Miss">Miss</option>
<option value="Ms">Ms</option>
</select>
<label>Contact Number:</label>
<input type="text" class="input phone" placeholder="Your number" name="number">
<label>First name:</label>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="John" name="fname"/>
<label>Surname:</label>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Doe" name="sname"/>
<label>Email:</label>
<input type="email" class="input email" placeholder="something@domain.com" name="email"/>
<label>Postcode:</label>
<input type="text" class="input zipcode" placeholder="CW3 9SS" name="post"/>
<label>Date of birth:</label>
<select class="input dateDay" name="day">
<option>Day</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>17</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>19</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>21</option>
<option>22</option>
<option>23</option>
<option>24</option>
<option>25</option>
<option>26</option>
<option>27</option>
<option>28</option>
<option>29</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>31</option>
</select>
<select class="input dateMonth" name="month">
<option>Month</option>
<option>January</option>
<option>February</option>
<option>March</option>
<option>April</option>
<option>May</option>
<option>June</option>
<option>July</option>
<option>August</option>
<option>September</option>
<option>October</option>
<option>November</option>
<option>December</option>
</select>
<select class="input dateYear" name="year">
<option>Year</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1943">1943</option>
<option value="1942">1942</option>
<option value="1941">1941</option>
<option value="1940">1940</option>
<option value="1939">1939</option>
<option value="1938">1938</option>
<option value="1937">1937</option>
<option value="1936">1936</option>
<option value="1935">1935</option>
<option value="1934">1934</option>
<option value="1933">1933</option>
<option value="1932">1932</option>
<option value="1931">1931</option>
<option value="1930">1930</option>
<option value="1929">1929</option>
<option value="1928">1928</option>
<option value="1927">1927</option>
<option value="1926">1926</option>
<option value="1925">1925</option>
<option value="1924">1924</option>
<option value="1923">1923</option>
<option value="1922">1922</option>
<option value="1921">1921</option>
<option value="1920">1920</option>
<option value="1919">1919</option>
<option value="1918">1918</option>
<option value="1917">1917</option>
<option value="1916">1916</option>
<option value="1915">1915</option>
<option value="1914">1914</option>
<option value="1913">1913</option>
</select>
<label>Where did you hear about us:</label>
<select class="input" name="hear">
<option value="google">Google</option>
<option value="recommendation">Recommendation</option>
<option value="email">Email</option>
<option value="Magazine">Magazine</option>
<option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div class="form_error" style="display:none;color:red;text-align:center;text-shadow:none;"></div>
<input class="darkBtn submit" type="submit" value="Send my message »" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
<?php
} if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "**REMOVED**";
$emailfrom = "**REMOVED**";
$subject = "Insurance Quote";
$message="\r\n Title:" . $title . "\r\n First Name:" . $fname . "\r\n Surname:" . $_POST['sname'] . "\r\n Number: " . $_POST['number1'] . "\r\n Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n Post: " . $_POST['post'] . "\r\n Day: " . $_POST['day'] . "\r\n Month: " . $_POST['year'] . "\r\n Hear: " . $_POST['hear'];
$headers = "From:" . $emailfrom;

if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
echo "Thankyou for using **REMOVED**";
}
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:
When i remove the jQuery validation the page sends perfect.

However, if i keep the jQuery validation in then the page does not do Anything when i press submit.**

Comment: Where is the problem ? Form validation ? Form data not posted ? PHP issue ?

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to add that part :$ - Updated OP

Comment: look at the javascript console. your validation is probably throwing an error, or triggering "invalid" successfully, but you're not acting on the validation result. If it works without the javascript, then that is obviously the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your submit button's name from 'submit' to something else and try.

Comment: I modified your code and its working fine for me. Here is the link http://codepad.org/9Dx952Tj

Comment: Hi mate, what did you modify? Just the submit button?

Comment: Hi mate, That works great. Really appreciate it. I was going to ask why but saw @elcodedocle write the reason why. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the form action.

```
<form method="POST" class="form_contact" id="contact_form" action="receiver.php">
```

Comment: It doesnt have one as it does it to the same page

Comment: Had you tried `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` ?

Comment: By the way, you should user `$_POST['fname']` instead of `$fname`

Answer (score 1):

If your web server access log shows you are receiving the POST request, there is probably an error on `mail()`. Try adding this `else`:

```
if ($mailerror = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
    echo "Thankyou for using **REMOVED**";
} else {
    echo "Error: cannot send email.";
}
```

and check if you see the error message instead of a blank page.

(If not, check the browser console to see if the error is in the JavaScript code).

**EDIT**

I also detected a problem naming the input "submit" (apparently it overrides the form's default submit behaviour, probably when you call `e.preventDefault();`
), just rename it and everything will be peachy. Here's is a working solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sent'])){
}
else {
?>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


function isInt(n) {
return typeof n === 'number' && n % 1 == 0;
}

// Form validation
$(".darkBtn").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var email_check = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i;
var email = $("form.form_contact .email").val();

var zipCheck = /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}/i;
var zip = $("form.form_contact .zipcode").val();

var phoneCheck = /^\d+$/;
var phone = jQuery("#contact_form .phone").val();
console.log(phone);

var error = "";

if(!email_check.test(email))
{
error = "Please give a valid email address."

}

if(!zipCheck.test(zip))
{
error = "Please give a valid postcode.";
}

if(!phoneCheck.test(phone) || phone.length != 11)
{
error = "Please give a valid phone number.";
}


// No error ? -> Submit
if(error == "")
{
$(".form_error").hide();
$('#contact_form').submit();
console.log("sent.");
} else {
$(".form_error").empty().text(error);
$(".form_error").show();
}
});
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu_contact">
<h3>Contact Us</h3>
<hr />
<form method="post" class="form_contact" id="contact_form">
<label>Title:</label>
<select class="input" name="title">
<option value="no">Please select</option>
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
<option value="Miss">Miss</option>
<option value="Ms">Ms</option>
</select>
<label>Contact Number:</label>
<input type="text" class="input phone" placeholder="Your number" name="number">
<label>First name:</label>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="John" name="fname"/>
<label>Surname:</label>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Doe" name="sname"/>
<label>Email:</label>
<input type="email" class="input email" placeholder="something@domain.com" name="email"/>
<label>Postcode:</label>
<input type="text" class="input zipcode" placeholder="CW3 9SS" name="post"/>
<label>Date of birth:</label>
<select class="input dateDay" name="day">
<option>Day</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>17</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>19</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>21</option>
<option>22</option>
<option>23</option>
<option>24</option>
<option>25</option>
<option>26</option>
<option>27</option>
<option>28</option>
<option>29</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>31</option>
</select>
<select class="input dateMonth" name="month">
<option>Month</option>
<option>January</option>
<option>February</option>
<option>March</option>
<option>April</option>
<option>May</option>
<option>June</option>
<option>July</option>
<option>August</option>
<option>September</option>
<option>October</option>
<option>November</option>
<option>December</option>
</select>
<select class="input dateYear" name="year">
<option>Year</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1943">1943</option>
<option value="1942">1942</option>
<option value="1941">1941</option>
<option value="1940">1940</option>
<option value="1939">1939</option>
<option value="1938">1938</option>
<option value="1937">1937</option>
<option value="1936">1936</option>
<option value="1935">1935</option>
<option value="1934">1934</option>
<option value="1933">1933</option>
<option value="1932">1932</option>
<option value="1931">1931</option>
<option value="1930">1930</option>
<option value="1929">1929</option>
<option value="1928">1928</option>
<option value="1927">1927</option>
<option value="1926">1926</option>
<option value="1925">1925</option>
<option value="1924">1924</option>
<option value="1923">1923</option>
<option value="1922">1922</option>
<option value="1921">1921</option>
<option value="1920">1920</option>
<option value="1919">1919</option>
<option value="1918">1918</option>
<option value="1917">1917</option>
<option value="1916">1916</option>
<option value="1915">1915</option>
<option value="1914">1914</option>
<option value="1913">1913</option>
</select>
<label>Where did you hear about us:</label>
<select class="input" name="hear">
<option value="google">Google</option>
<option value="recommendation">Recommendation</option>
<option value="email">Email</option>
<option value="Magazine">Magazine</option>
<option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div class="form_error" style="display:none;color:red;text-align:center;text-shadow:none;"></div>
<input class="darkBtn submit" type="button" value="Send my message »" name="smit">
<input type="hidden" name="sent" value="true"/>
</form>
</div>
<?php
} if (isset($_POST['sent'])) {

$to = "**REMOVED**";
$emailfrom = "**REMOVED**";
$subject = "Insurance Quote";
$message="\r\n Title:" . $_POST['title'] . "\r\n First Name:" . $_POST['fname'] . "\r\n Surname:" . $_POST['sname'] . "\r\n Number: " . $_POST['number'] . "\r\n Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n Post: " . $_POST['post'] . "\r\n Day: " . $_POST['day'] . "\r\n Month: " . $_POST['year'] . "\r\n Hear: " . $_POST['hear'];
$headers = "From:" . $emailfrom;

echo "Thankyou for using **REMOVED**";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also, check the php log for the warning to see why the email couldn't be sent. (probably bad config of your smtp server).

Comment: There was a typo in my email -_-  - however, with the jQuery validation added back into it, nothing happens after i press submit for some reason

Comment: I don't know. I tried your code and it works fine for me (adding a jquery library request before the jquery script, of course). Tried also in jsfiddle, no problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3G9wS/4/

Comment: Yeah i had to remove the request due to a conflict. It had already been requested on another part of the page. But im trying it on a standalone page with the request left in

Comment: Hi mate, Thanks alot for the explanation of why the Submit button did what it did. Yours and @LX7's answers were right. Works perfect. Thanks